# Sum of homogeneous and inhomogeneous solutions also form a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For some linear differential operator, $L$, an inhomogeneous differential equation can be formed: 
$$ L~y(x) = F(x)  \text{ with some solution }  y_p (x).$$
Similarly a homogeneous equation could be formed such that:
$$ L~y(x) = 0   \text{ with some solution }  y_c (x).$$
My question is, how would I go about showing that $y (x) = y_p (x) + y_c (x)$ is also a solution to the inhomogeneous equation?

I could find solutions to both equations, sum them and resubstitute them in but would this be sufficient. As such, I can show that this is correct for some particular form of L but I am not sure how to show this for any general case.

Thanks for any advice given, Sean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we find the homogeneous solution of inhomogeneous Differential Equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264847/why-do-we-find-the-homogeneous-solution-of-inhomogeneous-differential-equations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is linear then what does that mean?

$$L(a+b)=?.$$

Now apply this to

$$L(y_p+y_c).$$

In fact this only used the fact that $L$ is additive. If $L$ is linear it also has the property

$$L(\lambda a)=\lambda La,$$
for a scalar $\lambda$.

This shows that $y_p+\lambda y_c$ is a solution also.

Comment: Thanks, by considering this the solution is now elegant and straightforward.