# Why do we find the homogeneous solution of inhomogeneous Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

We all know that if we have inhomogeneous differential equation, we must solve for homogeneous solution and the inhomogeneous solution. And, in the end, we add them together for the complete solution.

Suppose i have simple ODE :

$y''+2y'+y=x$

And i got :

$y_h=\left(C_1+xC_2\right)e^{-x}\\
y_p=x-2\\$
$
 \begin{aligned} \therefore y &= y_h+y_p\\
&=\left(C_1+xC_2\right)e^{-x}+x-2
\end{aligned}$

But i know that the inhomogeneous solution ($y_p$) is satisfied enough for that ODE, so why don't we use the $y_p$ only?

Lately, This question appear in my mind and sometimes it's annoying cz i still can't answer it.

Comment: When solving differential equations we want to get the most general solution. The particular solution is a solution to the differential equations, but when we sum the homogenous solution and particular solution we get all possible solutions to the differential equation. If we don't add the homogenous part, we might miss some possible solutions. There are some assumptions/hypotheses about differentiability/smoothness that need to be considered later to make these theorems precise, but in an early stage of differential equations, this probably won't be the focus.

Comment: We want to find all the solutions, not just one. Suppose you had the initial value problem: $y''+2y'+y=x$, $y(0)=0$. The particular solution $y=x-2$ satisfies the differential equation but does not satisfy the initial condition. What now?

Comment: Besides that, some methods for finding a particular soution $y_p$, for instance "variation of parameters" or "undetermined coefficients", require us to find the homogeneous solution $y_h$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in general we solve initial value problems.  The reason for adding the homogenous solution to the particular solution is to find the general solution and be able to find solutions which satisfy  any given initial conditions.

A particular solution satisfies a particular initial condition which is not necessarily what we  are looking for.